# go-staticcheck: should use a simple channel send/receive instead of select with a single case (S1000)

Tags: go, static-code-analysis, channel

I am using Go 1.16.4. I am trying to deal with such code:

```golang
func (pool *myConnPool) GetPooledConnection() (*myConnection, error) {
    go func() {
        conn, err := pool.createConn()
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        pool.connections <- conn
    }()
    select { // <<<< golint warning here
    case conn := <-pool.connections:
        return pool.packConn(conn), nil
    }
}
```

I am getting following Go linter warning: `should use a simple channel send/receive instead of select with a single case (S1000)` at the point marked in the code. Can anyone please explain how to fix that? I am not yet too experienced with Go channels.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The linter is telling you that your use of `select` is meaningless with only a single `case`.
To solve the problem, replace this:

```golang
select {
case conn := <-pool.connections:
    return pool.packConn(conn), nil
}
```

With:

```
conn := <-pool.connections
return pool.packConn(conn), nil
```

Or even:

```
return pool.packConn(<-pool.connections), nil
```